# Cx_Freeze and Plotly

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze, plotly, pkg-resources

I am trying to build an exe of an application that uses plotly using cx_freeze.

I have previously built the application using matplotlib but have switched the graphing over to plotly.

I can build the application but when I try to plot, I get the following error.

```
 url = py.plot(fig, filename='pandas-box-plot')

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 284, in p
lot
    get_plotlyjs(),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 48, in ge
t_plotlyjs
    plotlyjs = resource_string('plotly', path).decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1184, in
resource_string
    self, resource_name
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1457, in
get_resource_string
    return self._get(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1535, in
_get
    return self.loader.get_data(path)
OSError: [Errno 0] Error: 'plotly\\offline\\plotly.min.js'
```

I have tried including pkg_resources in the setup.py file and have also included the plotly.min.js in the PATH_to_exe\offline\plotly.min.js.

As far as I can tell the pkg_resources has the problem?

Edit: It seems like pkg_resources is looking for the file in the library.zip file, but it is included in the path outside of the library.zip. I can't seem to find a way to add the files to the library.zip file in the setup.py

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. You can include the files in the setup.py. First create the list of files to include, like in the normal includes. python_dir is the path to your python directory that contains the files.

```
zip_includes = [('%s\Lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\plotly.min.js' % str(python_dir), 'plotly\offline\plotly.min.js'),
                ('%s\Lib\site-packages\plotly\widgets\graphWidget.js' % str(python_dir), 'plotly\widgets\graphWidget.js'),
                ('%s\Lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_reference\default-schema.json' % str(python_dir), 'plotly\graph_reference\default-schema.json')]
```

Then in your setup:

```
    setup(name="Orion",
          version="1",
          author="Jonathan",
          description="Metering analysis tool",
          options={'build_exe': {'excludes': excludes, 'packages': packages, 'include_files': include_files, 'build_exe': "%s/build" % BASE_PATH, 'zip_includes': zip_includes}},
          executables=[compileTarget]
          )
```

This will include the files inside the library.zip and will not include them like the typical external files to include.

Comment: A year late but, can you show more of your setup file? Idk what packages and excludes you used. Having trouble with getting cx_Freeze to run myself.